# How to write an array without length

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that looks for three numbers in array that gives an arithmetic sequence of length three - three numbers a,b and c form an arithmetic sequence of length 3 if: b-a = c-b.

I have 2 problems:

1. I need to read an arbitrary number type int, and put them inside an array. for example: java string 3 4 5 6, gives array: [3],[4],[5],[6].
   and I couldn't do it because when creating an array it asks for the array length.
2. I guess I have a problem when writing the math command for `b-a = c-b`.

.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int [] a = new int [10];
    for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
      a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(a.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

      for (int j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
        int sum = a[i]-a[j];
        int tempa = a[i];
        int d = a[i+1];
        int c = a[i+2];
        if (d == tempa+d && c == tempa +  2*d)
            System.out.println("yes");

        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: You don't need to specify the length when instantiating an array. `int[] i = {0}`.

Comment: For you first problem, have a look at [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

### Option 1 -- Ask for length ahead of time

I don't think this option requires much explanation. It would look something like this

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int length = in.nextInt();
//... use "length" as you wish
```

### Option 2 -- Use an [`ArrayList`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist-java)!

Your code would then look a little something like this:

```
int inputNum = in.nextInt();
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (inputNum != 1){
    a.add(inputNum);
}
//you can use "a" as you wish now
```

Comment: Could you provide a `Java` link? This one is called `dotnetperls`

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, use an ArrayList to change the size of your list dynamically. Then you can use `yourList.add()` to assign values when needed. Check out the official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, creating an array of integers from a `String`, already have most of it. You just haven't figured out that the size of the `args` array is the number of `String` values to parse. You already know how to use the `length` attribute of `array`.

Here's my solution:

```
public class ThreeArithmeticSequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = new int[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(a.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length - 1; j++) {
                int b = a[j];
                for (int k = j + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
                    int c = a[k];

                    if (b - a[i] == c - b) {
                        System.out.println("yes");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but for the example: 20 8 27 19 10 56 7 12 98, we do have sequence of length 3 (8-10-12), but it doesn't get inside the loop tho.

Comment: Ah, it is a sequence, but not consecutive. Ok, no problem. Will edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you! but it's still doesn't work. for the example:  20 8 27 19 10 56 7 12 98, it doesn't get inside the if command. I tried many things but still doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry. Stupid typo. `int c = a[k];`